# Python: How to evaluate a function which is string?

Tags: python

I get some models from database as

```
f(t)=(2.128795454425367)+(208.54359721863273)*t+(26.098128487929266)*t^2+(3.34369909584111)*t^3+(-0.3450228278737971)*t^4+(-0.018630757967458885)*t^5+(0.0015029038553239819)*t^6;
```

which somes as string.

I need to evaluate this function for `t in range(1, 13)`

Right now I have to manually copy these functions and run them

```
   print [1.2381648958643592 + \
          153.55656654019816 * t +\
          22.99318731025164 * (t**2) +\
          11.060577906796075 * (t**3) +\
          -1.3465054084767891 * (t**4) + \
          0.016926765998876842 * (t**5) +\
          0.001500086893490721 * (t**6) for t in range(1, 13)]
```

Is there a better way to do it in python?

Comment: If the expressions were in Python, there are some shortcuts you would be able to take. However, since they are in a different language, a proper solution would involve creating a parser for this other language.

Comment: You can parse it with regular expressions or use `eval`, but the latter will also require some preprocessing in this case.

Comment: How are the models being generated? Is there a way to generate them as Python code instead of whatever other language they are?

Comment: If the model language is set in stone, you might want to include a complete description of that language in your question. If it's simple enough, there may be a simple solution.

Comment: What conclusions can we draw from your example?  That all constants are always encapsulated in ()?  that exponents are already sequential and unbroken?

Comment: What language are the models written in? We know `^` probably means exponent, but `import this` suggests we should avoid guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance isn't a major concern -- and if you're only evaluating it at 12 points, I suspect it's not -- then you can leverage the handy [sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) library to do a lot of the work for you.  For example:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.sympify("t**5 - t + 3")
t**5 - t + 3
>>> sympy.sympify("t**5 - t + 3").subs({"t": 10})
99993
```

We can wrap this up in a function which returns a function:

```
import sympy

def definition_to_function(s):
    lhs, rhs = s.split("=", 1)
    rhs = rhs.rstrip('; ')
    args = sympy.sympify(lhs).args
    f = sympy.sympify(rhs)
    def f_func(*passed_args):
        argdict = dict(zip(args, passed_args))
        result = f.subs(argdict)
        return float(result)
    return f_func
```

which we can then apply, even to more complex cases beyond the easy reach of regex:

```
>>> s = "f(t)=(2.128795454425367)+(208.54359721863273)*t+(26.098128487929266)*t^2+(3.34369909584111)*t^3+(-0.3450228278737971)*t^4+(-0.018630757967458885)*t^5+(0.0015029038553239819)*t^6;"
>>> f = definition_to_function(s)
>>> f(0)
2.128795454425367
>>> f(10)
4230.6764921149115
>>> f = definition_to_function("f(a,b,c) = sin(a)+3*b-4*c")
>>> f(1,2,3)
-5.158529015192103
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(1)+3*2-4*3
-5.158529015192103
```

Comment: Great lib, yet the warning seems to explicitly alert about the same danger as `eval()`: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#converting-strings-to-sympy-expressions

Comment: @vinyll: yep.  They use `eval` along the path, and so it's not safe for untrusted input.  But it's very convenient.

Comment: @DSM I couldn't figure out what was the bonus with the package over a raw `eval()`. I guess I didn't have the need and ended with a raw native unsecured `eval()` (Yet it's not a user input).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the 'function' string, you could do something like this:

```
import re

s = "f(t)=(2.128795454425367)+(208.54359721863273)*t+(26.098128487929266)*t^2\
    +(3.34369909584111)*t^3+(-0.3450228278737971)*t^4+(-0.018630757967458885)*t^5\
    +(0.0015029038553239819)*t^6;"

def f(t):
    l = map(float, re.findall("-?\\d+\\.\\d+", s))
    return sum(b * t**a for a,b in enumerate(l))

print map(f, xrange(1,13))
```

```
[239.75206957484252, 544.337732955938, 921.544112756058, 1366.6221363666925, 1864.8848673959649, 2393.2591324279497, 2922.9192385578326, 3423.0027817028927, 3865.4085456893295, 4230.676492114911, 4514.949840987468, 4738.019242139209]
```

This approach assumes that the function string will always be of the form

```
c0 + c1 t + c2 t^2 + c3 t^4 + ... cn t^(n+1)
```

and works by extracting the floating point numbers from the string and using them to generate an actual Python function.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the function as a python expersion in your database and when you get the string just do something like eval(funcstr.replace('x', 'yvalue')).

To show you an example:

```
funcstr = '2*x+5'
evalpoint = funcstr.replace('x', '5')
val = eval(funcstr)
```

At this point val should be evaluated to 15

Comment: Could you use this approach to adapt this string into Python?

Answer (score 0):

As NPE says, the right answer here is to write a parser (and simple interpreter) for your expression language.

Or, even better, if at all possible, generate the expressions in Python in the first place, instead of in a language which is almost but not quite compatible with a subset of Python.

Or, even better, if the language is just a way to represent the list of coefficients for a polynomial, just represent it as a list of coefficients, which will be a lot easier to parse than any actual general-purpose language. For example, let's say the database held this:

```
2.128795454425367, 208.54359721863273, 26.098128487929266, 3.34369909584111, -0.3450228278737971, -0.018630757967458885, 0.0015029038553239819
```

Then, to execute that in Python, you'd do this:

```
def eval_polynomial(polynomial, value):
    coefficients = [float(x.strip()) for x in polynomial.split(',')]
    return sum(coefficient * (value**exponent) 
               for exponent, coefficient in enumerate(coefficients))
```

Then:

```
>>> [eval_polynomial(expr, t) for t in range(1, 13)]
```

But if you really, really want to do this without changing what's in the database, you could just transform it into a Python expression and eval it:

```
>>> expr = 'f(t)=(2.128795454425367)+(208.54359721863273)*t+(26.098128487929266)*t^2+(3.34369909584111)*t^3+(-0.3450228278737971)*t^4+(-0.018630757967458885)*t^5+(0.0015029038553239819)*t^6;'
>>> removef = re.sub(r'f\((\w+)\)=', 'lambda \1: ', expr)
>>> fixpower = re.sub(r'(\w+)\^(\d+)', r'(\1**\2)', removef)
>>> nosemi = fixpower.replace(';', '')
>>> func = eval(nosemi)
>>> [func(t) for t in range(1, 13)]
[239.75206957484252, 544.337732955938, 921.544112756058, 1366.6221363666925, 1864.8848673959649, 2393.2591324279497, 2922.9192385578326, 3423.0027817028927, 3865.4085456893295, 4230.676492114911, 4514.949840987468, 4738.019242139209]
```

But again, you probably don't want to do this.

And, if you do, you probably want to write a transformer that works on your actual language, rather than on a stab-in-the-dark guess at your language based on a single example…

Answer (score 0):

if you trust your sources you can do it like this with regex and eval:

```
# deletes the simicolon and everything before the space
my_str = start_str.split('=')[1][:-1]
# change ^ to ** because that's the squared operator
my_str = re.sub('\^', '**', my_str)
# substitute the t for the numbers 1 to 13 and evaluate the string
results = [eval(re.sub('t', str(t), my_str)) for t in range(1,13)]
```