# input a symbolic function in a python code

Tags: python, sympy

I was just wondering if there is a method to input a symbolic function in a python code?

like in my code I have:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import math
myfunction = input("enter your function \n")
l = Symbol('l')

print myfunction(l**2).diff(l)
```

If I put cos, sin or exp, as an input then I have an output of:  `-2*l*sin(l**2)`

What If I want to make the input function more general, say a polynomial or a complex function, or maybe a function of combined cos, sin and exp ???

Comment: Isn't this the default behavior of `input` in python 2 ? (that is, to _eval_)

Comment: yes, but when I put a function like : sin + cos, or a polinomial : x**2 + 2*x +1. the code above fail !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need good support for symbolic funcions, you should consider using [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).

It is a preprocessor for python, with lots of math support including symbolic functions. Sage code can be intermixed with normal python-code.

The package is quite big, but I have good experiences with it. It is free and open-source.

Comment: No - it's more than freeware - `Sage is a free open-source mathematics software system licensed under the GPL`

Comment: Thanks, Someone was faster than me to change the answer.

Comment: Thank you, i know about sage, and there is a package for python called: sage.all ... but I didn't find from where to download it ??

Comment: You can download for Linux on: http://www.sagemath.org/download-linux.html, Windows seems to be http://www.sagemath.org/download-windows.html. I have never tried it on Windows.

Answer (score 11):

As a syntax, `sin + cos` simply isn't going to work very well.  The simplest way to get the general case to work is to give sympy an *expression* to evaluate.   We can let `sympify` do the hard work of turning a string into a `sympy` object:

```
>>> s = raw_input("enter a formula: ")
enter a formula: sin(x) + x**3
>>> s
'sin(x) + x**3'
>>> f = sympy.sympify(s)
>>> f
x**3 + sin(x)
```

After which we can substitute and evaluate:

```
>>> f.subs({'x': 2})
sin(2) + 8
>>> f.subs({'x': 2}).evalf()
8.90929742682568
```

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734176/487339) for some other tricks you can pull with a bit of work:

```
>>> f = definition_to_function("f(x) = sin(x) + x**3")
>>> f(3)
27.14112000805987
```