# Python User input equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, equation, differential-equations

I'm writing a simple python script to solve differential equations using Eulers method and right now i have to change the source code every time i want to solve a new equation.

(Safety isn't of any concern at the moment as this is a personal project.)

**My question:**
Would it be possible to type in an equation as user input and make it to a variable? For example, using `e=input("enter equation")` where you enter `y/x`, and making `e` a variable for later use?

```
#I would like to be able to type in a equation as user input and turn it to a variable for later use in the if and elif segments, example

    e=input("Enter your equation here")
    e=float(e)


    h=input("Ange steglängd: ")
    h=float(h)

    x=input("Angivet värde på x: ") 
    x=float(x)

    y=input("Värde på y med anseende på x: ") 
    y=float(y)

    z=input("Närmevärde du vill ha för y(x), ange x: ") 
    z=float(z)


    if x<z:
        while x<z:

            #Type in equation below as e

            e=y/x

            y=y+h*e 
            x+=h    

        print(y)

    elif x>z: 
        while x>z:

            e=y/x

            y=y-h*e
            x-=h

        print(y)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the equation. You could parse, and turn it into an abstract syntax tree. Or you could parse it into postfix notation.

Comment: I simply plan to use the equation as a variable which later on is used to solve for an answer, quite new to python and not sure how to further explain my needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input a symbolic function in a python code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369106/input-a-symbolic-function-in-a-python-code)

Comment: Check the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15369443/4230591) of the duplicate. However, be careful with `sympify()` (and other SymPy functions) since it uses `eval()` and can execute malicious input.

Comment: Went through that code earlier today and failed. Granted I'm only a beginner and I'll give it another try

Comment: @Chrizzy Does using `y = y + h * e.subs({'x': x, 'y': y})` in your code, fix your problem? If so, please mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Chrizzy To be more precise... use `from sympy import *`, then use `e = sympify(input('give equation:'))` and finally change your code to `y = y + h * e.subs({'x': x, 'y': y})`. (I don't want to post it as an answer since it would be duplicating content on the site, which is not good.)

Comment: I agree with Fermi's earlier comment: if this works best for you, please mark your question as a duplicate, and unselect my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tack för exempel -- that allowed me to determine what you need.

Yes, this is possible.  Read in the equation as a string variable, such as

```
equation = input("Enter your equation here")
```

Then when you want to find a value for **e**, use the Python [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) method:

```
e = eval(equation)
```

Be very careful with this method: `eval()` is powerful, and very discriminating about what it accepts.

- [eval is really
  dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)
- [Security on untrusted
  strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings/661128#661128)

Comment: If he'll be using a string provided by a user, he **must not** use `eval()`. There is no way to make it safe.

Comment: But then again, even SymPy uses `eval()` currently in some of its methods. So, maybe this answer is not bad, as long as it contains a big warning on why it's dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eval` in combination with lambda functions, like this:

```
e = eval('lambda x, y: x/y')
```

To actually have this interactive, use `raw_input()` to obtain the actual expression (`'lambda x, y: x/y'` in this case). Or if you prefer not to type the whole `lambda` wording, and provided that you'll always have the independent variable `x` and the dependent variable `y`, in an equation like `y = f(x)`, you could write something like this:

```
e = eval('lambda x, y: ' + raw_input('enter equation for y=f(x): '))
```

And then you'd enter the `'x/y'` when you're prompted to.

However, are you sure you need it *inside* the `while` loop?