# Is there a way for Python to accept non-string literal input?

Tags: python

This problem has been getting in my way over and over:

Is there any way to make the input() function in python not be read as a string, nor an integer, nor a float? Let me explain:

I am trying to make an input where I can reference a variable in the input. Here is an example of what I need to do:

```
def main():
    x = 2

    # Below, I would enter x*x as my function.
    fx = (input("Please enter your Function: ")

    print(fx)

main()
```

I would hope to receive 4 (i.e. 2*2) as my output, but instead I get "x*x". In other words, python is not recognizing that I am referring to a variable (i.e. x) in my program. It thinks I'm writing a string.
So is there any way for python to receive input that is not a string or a specific number?
In other words: Can input variables into my input? I don't want all my input to be converted to string literals. (I am aware of the fact that I could use int() and float() functions to get numbers, but I need to input variables, not actual numbers in this case).
Sorry about the length of my question

Comment: You **really** shouldn't do this. For starters, `input` will **always** return a `str`, you are entering *text* after all. You want to *evaluate that text as Python source code*, so you could use `eval`. But again, there is almost certainly a much saner way to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to accomplish. This is almost certainly the X-Y problem

Comment: " It thinks I'm writing a string" It doesn't *think* that. You are *writing text data*, which is most reasonably represented as a `str` object. " I don't want all my input to be converted to string literals. " It isn't converted to sting literals, it is a `str` object. String literals are a *feature of source code*, they aren't a type of object (they are a feature of source code that create `str` objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369106/input-a-symbolic-function-in-a-python-code)

Note: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369106/input-a-symbolic-function-in-a-python-code) previous question:

**Code**

```
import sympy as sym

def main():
    x = 2
    s = input("Please enter your Function: ")  # String expression
    fx = sym.sympify(s)                        # create symbolic expression from string
    
    print('Symbolic expression: ', fx)         # print symbolic expression
    print('Value of expresion: ', fx.subs({'x' : x})) # substitute for x in expression
     
main()
```

**Output**

```
Please enter your Function: x*x
Symbolic expression:  x**2
Value of expression:  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to do what you want:

```
def main():
    x = 2

    # Below, I would enter x*x as my function.
    fx = (input("Please enter your Function: "))  # x*x
    print(eval(fx))

main()
```

**Output**

```
4
```

But honestly, this is almost never a good idea. If you are expecting different sorts of inputs, it's better to check the string entered and use some `if..else` logic to understand what the input really wants.

Keep in mind eval runs all expressions. So (if you have to worry about this sort of thing), someone with malicious intent could also execute anything they want using this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your values into a dict (using the name of the variable as the key in the dict), you can convert the name (a string) into the value via a dictionary lookup.  For example:

```
nums = {
    "x": 2,
    "y": 3,
}

ops = {
    "*": int.__mul__,
    "+": int.__add__,
}

while True:
    fx = input("Please enter your function:")
    a, op, b = fx
    print(ops[op](nums[a], nums[b]))
```

```
Please enter your function:x*x
4
Please enter your function:x+y
5
Please enter your function:y*x
6
```