# How to read in function body from input()?

Tags: python, arrays, input, lambda

In the chunk of code below, I'm trying to define 3 functions in my input_strats array. Why does it only prompt the user and then print "defined 1" once? Thanks!

```
 prev_used = 3
 input_strats = [0 for x in range(prev_used)]
 for i in range(prev_used):
     input_strats[i] = lambda alpha,beta,x,z,year: input('Expression here\n')
     print("defined 1\n")
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry about that.. I made some progress and now have a much more concise question. I hope you can help!

Comment: Okay, I removed my comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Turning functions into a list is easy in Python: just list the function names, like so:

```
def year1(a, b):
    return 0.9*a + 0.1*b

def year2(a, b):
    return (a+b) / 2.0

def year3(a, b):
    return a**2 + b**2

func_list = [year1, year2, year3]

for udf in func_list:
    print udf
    print udf(2, 5)
```

Gives the output you'd expect:

```
<function year1 at 0x1caa410>
2.3
<function year2 at 0x1caa500>
3.5
<function year3 at 0x1caa578>
29
```

Turning a string into a function requires a little trickery.  You decide on the input notation you want, and get strings that represent the left- and right-hand sides of the function definition.  Then you can create a generic function that returns a constructed function, using a dictionary of the parameters and the text to evaluate, as the function definition.  See this previous posting for coding details:
[function from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733493/python-how-to-evaluate-a-function-which-is-string#13734176)

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for your answer! A few questions though-- In your example, there were 3 functions. I general, how many functions is an input-- do I make a list and then append functions as I go? Additionally, using the sympy your linked post suggests, would that still work even if some of the inputs are arrays? Thanks again!!

Comment: You can just append as many functions as you like to the list.  I used 3 only because that was how you presented the problem.  Yes, you can use lists and arrays as arguments.  **definition_to_function** requires only that the string it builds eventually be a legal expression to evaluate: you can't write control loops and if statements (although list comprehensions and if clauses would be legal).

Comment: Is there any way that I could effectively have my python program run pure python code? It is fairly important that the strategies that come in (the functions) can include if-else logic. This is much harder than I thought! Do you think another language might be more sorted for this sort of thing? I'm just a bit lost at what I could go from here.

Comment: I haven't found anything yet; the experiments I tried failed.  However, note that you can have if-then *logic*, just not if-then *statements*.  For instance, you could have something like **f(a,b) = a+2*b if a > b else abs(a) if a < 0 else b*b"**.  I believe that it has to pass the *eval* function.

Comment: Hi Prune! So actually, the eval function was more or less what I was looking for! Lambda's are fairly complicated.. my general case is a user inputs a function body (simple) and then I need to evaluate it. Do you know if the eval function can run if/else logic? It seems like it could since there is also an eval_literal method. I'm having trouble typing in if-else statements to the terminal that it isn't yelling at me for. Any tips? Everything I try gets rejected.

Comment: I don't know of anything that will form a full-bodied function from text.  I don't have time to experiment more for the next few days, either; sorry.  As for if-then statements, try editing them in a file and running Python on the file.  Python command shells are generally not for development or non-trivial experimentation.